# Not able to run Golang binary inside Docker container

Tags: bash, docker, shell, go, dockerfile

I am trying to run golang code binary inside my docker container but I am unable to see the process inside the container or the log file generated using the code inside the binary. Please suggest if I am missing anything here.

```
FROM golang:1.19
WORKDIR /app
COPY  main /app
CMD ["./main"]. # Tried ["/bin/bash", "-c", "./main"] or ./main
```

I have already tried using -d with running container and checked the logs.

Comment: Maybe it ran and exited?

Comment: Hmm if it does, a log file would be generated because if I run the same command inside the container it will create my log file. So confused about what is missing from my end.

Comment: If your program writes to a log file inside docker, that log file is gone when the container terminates.

Comment: @StephenNewell Agree thanks for raising this point, my main objective is to set this script running in the background, Can you suggest what should be the way forward.?

Comment: Your container almost certainly ran to completion.  If you need it to run in the background, then you've already discovered the `-d` flag.  If you mean something else, [edit] your question with those details.

Comment: Have you tried to get into your container using `sh` (or `bash`), then run `./main`, so that you can see error messages ?

Comment: @Philippe Yes I did, I am able to see my code running using ./main